# Assembly program to add odd numbers using conditional jump

Tags: assembly, nasm, dos, 16-bit

I have a assignment:

> Write an Assembly code to add following fifteen odd numbers with using conditional jump.

Odd numbers: 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21,23,25,27,29,31

I make this solution. I want to check this whats wrong in it...

```
[org 0x0100]
mov bx, num1
mov cx, 15
mov ax, 0
li:
add ax, [bx]
add bx, 2
sub cx, 1
jnz li
mov ax, 0x4c00
int 0x21
num1: dw 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21,23,25,27,29,31
```

Comment: What makes you think there is something wrong with it? It appears okay to me

Comment: I am using AFD to find bugs... and code is not running on that... register overload type error will be written their.

Comment: Your code looked fine. Until now I have never used AFD.EXE. I downloaded it and I ran your code in that used F1 to step through your code until just *before* calling `mov ax, 0x4c00` `int 0x21` and _AX_ contained `0xFF` which is 255 in decimal. 3+5+7+9+11+13+15+17+19+ 21+23+25+27+29+31 = 255 so it looks good to me. Where do you see this register overfload type error? I assembled your code with `nasm -f bin testit.asm -o testit.com` . I then loaded DOSBOX and loaded it with  `AFD TESTIT.COM`

Comment: Why do you do `mov ax, 0x4c00`? It seem overwriting the result of addition.

Comment: @MikeCAT The OP failed to mention this part of the question _Explain each instruction of program and also provide/paste snapshot of your assemble and debug program result which will be run in AFD (A Full Screen Debugger) window showing the executed code final results in AX register._ . It appears that they are simply suppose to step through the debugger to find their value of _AX_ . I don't think it matters that _AX_ eventually gets clobbered (or not used)

Comment: mov ax, 0x4c00 is the problem... thanx @MikeCAT :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's certainly *one* way to do it, the only thing you need to be careful of is the fact you're accumulating the sum in `ax` but then you overwrite `ax` when you exit the program with `int 21, fn 4c`.

By a happy coincidence, those numbers sum to 255 so it will actually *fit* into `al`, which is the register used for the return code by that interrupt (see [Ralf Brown's excellent interrupt list](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2974.htm)).

Whether DOS will do anything intelligent with it, I couldn't say :-)

In order to preserve `al` when you exit the program, simply do this instead:

```
mov  ah, 0x4c
int  0x21
```

---

The other thing you may want to consider doing is to print the item directly rather than returning it. The following code shows how to do this, using a function from my arsenal, capable of outputting the `al` register as a base-ten value:

```
        org     00100h

        mov     bx, num1
        mov     cx, 15
        mov     ax, 0
li:
        add     ax, [bx]
        add     bx, 2
        sub     cx, 1
        jnz     li

        call    prt_byte

        mov     ah, 04ch
        int     021h

num1:   dw      3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21,23,25,27,29,31
eoln:   db      0dh, 0ah, '$'

prt_byte:
        push    ax
        push    bx
        push    dx

        cmp     ax, 100
        jl      skip_h

        push    ax

        mov     bl, 100             ; divide ax by 100.
        div     bl
        mov     ah, 0

        call    prt_digit

        mul     bl                  ; remove hundreds digit.
        mov     bx, ax
        pop     ax
        sub     ax, bx

skip_h:
        cmp     ax, 10
        jl      skip_t

        push    ax

        mov     bl, 10              ; divide ax by 10.
        div     bl
        mov     ah, 0

        call    prt_digit

        mul     bl                  ; remove tens digit.
        mov     bx, ax
        pop     ax
        sub     ax, bx

skip_t:
        call    prt_digit

        mov     dx, offset eoln
        mov     ah, 9
        int     021h

        pop     dx
        pop     bx
        pop     ax
        ret

prt_digit:
        push    ax                  ; save registers.
        push    dx

        mov     dx, ax              ; put in correct register.
        add     dx, '0'             ; turn into digit.
        mov     ah, 2               ; print.
        int     021h

        pop     dx                  ; restore registers and return.
        pop     ax
        ret
```

Comment: For a 0-99 integer, `div r8` by 10 gives you the 2 digits you want in printing order (quotient = MSD in `al`, which goes to the low address in memory = beginning of the string if you store `ax`).  So you can add `0x3030` (`'00'`) to turn that into two ASCII digits.  Or with a 32-bit register, `add eax, 0x0a3030` to turn the 3rd byte from 0 to newline.